# BinaryFormatter in cross-platform application

Tags: c#, android, winforms, xamarin

I'am creating cross-platform application. I'am trying to deserialize file in android. Everything is working fine in windows. This is my code:

```
[Serializable] //serializacja potrzebna do zapisywania do pliku.
public class dane
{
    public byte[] id { get; set; }
    public byte[] login { get; set; }
    public byte[] haslo { get; set; }
    public byte[] link { get; set; }
    public byte[] opis { get; set; }
    public byte[] dataWygasniecia { get; set; }

    public static List<dane> wczytajDaneDoListy(string sciezka) //deserializacja i wczytywanie danych z pliku
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(sciezka)) //jesli plik istnieje
            {
                Stream str = File.OpenRead(sciezka); //tworzenie strumienia
                var desrializer = new BinaryFormatter();//obiekt deserializujący
                //var desrializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<dane>)); //dla xml
                var listaDanych = (List<dane>)desrializer.Deserialize(str); //deserializacja do listy<dane>
                str.Close();
                return listaDanych;



            }
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null; //jesli plik nie istnieje, zwracamy null
        }
    }
    public static void zapiszDaneDoPliku() //serializacja i zapisywanie danych do pliku
    {
        Stream str = File.Create(zmienneGlobalne.sciezkaDoPliku); //tworzenie strumienia
        var serializer = new BinaryFormatter(); //obiekt serializujący
        serializer.Serialize(str, zmienneGlobalne.listaWpisow);
        //serializacja danych do strumienia(w tym wypadku do pliku)
        str.Close();
    }
}
```

When i try it in android using Xamarin - Debuger is stop working, without exception message. Error appears in line:

```
var listaDanych = (List<dane>)desrializer.Deserialize(str);
```

If I'am using XmlSerializer, it is wokring without problem.
How can I deserialize binnary file?
If binnaryFormater is not supported in android, i can use some other methods to serialize it to file. XML serialization is last way, because i want my file to be as hard to read as possible.

Comment: If you want it hard to read, encrypt it after you serialize it. Use AES and you just have to specify a little bit of information.

Comment: I know, that i can do it, my application using aes, but I want to know how to use binary formater in Android. Binary Formater, or any other tool that will work in windows and android to create binnary file.

Comment: Why? If you create a binary file, *anyone* can still read it with the right (easy to obtain) information. If you really want to secure it, use AES to encrypt it.

Comment: To expand my knowledge. It will be cool to know why this is not working, why it crash without any exception and how to solve this.

Comment: @titol What error do you get? Can you copy/paste the full exception with the stack trace? Or at least the exception with the message

Comment: Maybe this is an issue related to endianes?

Comment: @dr4cul4 Android should be little-endian, as Intel PC... Unless he is working on an old PowerMac as his desktop there sholdn't be any problem.

Comment: @dr4cul4 As I said in my post, there is no Exception. Debuger just stop working, and application is closed in emulator. I am using Xamarin Studio on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be platform-agnostic use serializers based on JSON or XML. Binary serialisation usually produces smaller file and is generally faster, but it is harder to code and may not be platform-agnostic.

If you inclined to use binary serialisation have a look at Protobuf serialiser.

Note that no serialisation can protect your file. If somebody wants to have a look inside - they will. If you want to protect the contents you'd generally follow this steps:

- Figure out a way to securely store encryption key
- Get bytes from serialised data
- Encrypt these bytes with the key and strong algorithm (such as AES)
- Save the result into binary file

If you need to send this data elsewhere, like submitting to web-service, you'd want to encode bytes into base64.

Reading from this file works in the opposite order

Comment: Sure, I got it, that serialization is not equal protection. As you can see data in my class is byte[]. I am using this type, because this is encrypted with AES. What i mean, is if user try to edit file with Notepad, i want him to see total mess, just like binnary file output. Also it is curious, that this serialization works perfectly fine with Windows, but does not work good with Android.